# How to free array of characters passed as function parameter in C

Tags: c, arrays, character

I came across an issue that I am not sure if it's an issue at all. I have a simple C funcion that gets a char* passed from string like so:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    passString("hello");

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void passString(char * string) {
    // .... some code ....
    free(string); // ???
}
```

and I was taught to free every memory block that I'm not working with anymore (mainly arrays). So my though was to free string as well but the program freezes or crashes even with this simple example. I'm not sure whether I really need to free string here or not and if so how do I achieve that?

Comment: @Kos: wrong, the type of a string literal is `char[N]` with `N` just large enough for all the characters in the string literal and a zero terminator. The type of `"foobar"` is `char[7]`. I believe there is a difference for other languages (namely C++).

Comment: Whoops... You're perfectly right. I actually meant "please use const char* to refer to string literals".

Comment: @Kos: Using just `char *` for string literal is only deprecated in C++ not in C.However,Yes modifying a string literal is UB in both c and c++.

Comment: Yup, I was referring to recommendation, not deprecation. C may not be as typesafe as C++, but keeping the good practice up doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not need to `free` memory which you did not allocate with `malloc`.

In your example `string` is not allocated by `malloc` in your program so you do not need to free it. `string` is a string literal and is allocated somewhere in the read-only memory(implementation defined) and is automatically freed.

For standerdese fans:

References:
**c99 Standard: 7.20.3.2 The `free` function**

> **Synopsis**
>      #include 
>   void free(void *ptr);
>
> **Description:**
>    The `free` function causes the space pointed to by ptr to be deallocated, that is, made
>   available for further allocation. If ptr is a null pointer, no action occurs. **Otherwise, if
>   the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by the `calloc`, `malloc`,or
>   `realloc` function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to `free` or `realloc`,
>   the behavior is undeﬁned**.
>
> **Returns**
>    The `free` function returns no value.

Answer (score 2):

The string you're freeing is statically allocated, "during compilation" if you will. Indeed any string literal (`"hello"`) is done this way. You cannot free statically allocated memory as it does not live in the heap.

As a general rule, it's actually better to free at the point of allocation. In this case, were you to dynamically allocate space for `"hello"`, you would do this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char *s = strdup("hello");
    passString(s);
    free(s);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void passString(char * string) {
    // .... some code ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need to free what you've allocated dynamically (via malloc in C or via keyword new in C++). Basically, for any allocation call like `malloc()` there should be a `free()` somewhere.

String literals aren't dynamically allocated and you don't need to be concerned about them.